# writting multiple xml nodes in a single xml file 

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

I have code using LINQ to XML. I wish to write that XElement every time into a new XML file, so that all the XML in it is stored in an XML file in a specified location.

```
XElement xml = new XElement("contacts",
                    new XElement("contact", 
                        new XAttribute("contactId", "2"),
                        new XElement("firstName", "Barry"),
                        new XElement("lastName", "Gottshall")
                    ),
                    new XElement("contact", 
                        new XAttribute("contactId", "3"),
                        new XElement("firstName", "Armando"),
                        new XElement("lastName", "Valdes")
                    )
                );


Console.WriteLine(xml);
```

I wsh to append the xml variable and add more nodes into it , I tried in following code but couldn't get it , I wish to write al the xml I get in EveryComment List

```
 XElement xml;
                    foreach (string Dcomment in EveryComment) 
                    {
                        string commentDetail = "http://www.edmunds.com" + Dcomment;
                        WebClient wc1 = new WebClient();
                        try { 
                            string comm = wc1.DownloadString(commentDetail);
                            string[] time_sep = { @"<time itemprop=""dtreviewed"" datetime=", "</time></div>" };
                            string[] car_split = {@"<span itemprop=""itemreviewed"">",@"</span><br/>        <div class=""header-5"">Review</div>"};
                            string[] name_comment_split = {@"<div class=""crr_by"">By <strong itemprop=""reviewer"">","</strong> on <time itemprop=",@"<div class=""header-5"">Review</div>        <span itemprop=""description"">",@"<div class=""header-5"">Favorite Features</div>" };
                            string[] get_name_comment = comm.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\t", "").Split(name_comment_split, StringSplitOptions.None);
                            string[] get_car_name = comm.Replace("\n","").Replace("\t","").Split(car_split, StringSplitOptions.None);
                            //CAR NAME AT 1 INDEX
                            string perfor,comfi,fuel,fun,interi,exteri,made,reliable;
                            string[] get_time = comm.Split(time_sep, StringSplitOptions.None);//TIME AT 1TH INDEX
                            comm = comm.Replace(@"""", "").Replace("\n"," ").Replace("\t"," ").Replace(" ","").Replace("\r","");
                            //HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                            //doc.LoadHtml(comm);
                            //var links = doc.DocumentNode.Name="span".Select(n => n.["href"].Value).ToArray();
                            string[] comm_split = { "Performance<hr/><spanclass=ratingtitle=", "Comfort<hr/><spanclass=ratingtitle=", "FuelEconomy<hr/><spanclass=ratingtitle=", "Fun-to-Drive<hr/><spanclass=ratingtitle=", "InteriorDesign<hr/><spanclass=ratingtitle=", "ExteriorDesign<hr/><spanclass=ratingtitle=", "BuildQuality<hr/><spanclass=ratingtitle=", "Reliability</div><spanclass=rating-bigtitle=","<divclass=header-5>FavoriteFeatures</div>", "<divclass=header-5>SuggestedImprovements</div>" };
                            string[] features = comm.Split(comm_split, StringSplitOptions.None);
                            if (features[1].ElementAt(1) == '.')
                            {

                                perfor = features[1].Substring(0, 3);
                            }
                            else
                                perfor = features[1].Substring(0, 1);
                            if (features[2].ElementAt(1) == '.')
                            {

                                comfi = features[2].Substring(0, 3);
                            }
                            else
                                comfi = features[2].Substring(0, 1);
                            if (features[3].ElementAt(1) == '.')
                            {

                                fuel = features[3].Substring(0, 3);
                            }
                            else
                                fuel = features[3].Substring(0, 1);
                            if (features[4].ElementAt(1) == '.')
                            {

                                fun = features[5].Substring(0, 3);
                            }
                            else
                                fun = features[5].Substring(0, 1);
                            if (features[6].ElementAt(1) == '.')
                            {

                                interi = features[6].Substring(0, 3);
                            }
                            else
                                interi = features[6].Substring(0, 1);

                            if (features[7].ElementAt(1) == '.')
                            {

                                exteri = features[7].Substring(0, 3);
                            }
                            else
                                exteri = features[7].Substring(0, 1);

                            if (features[8].ElementAt(1) == '.')
                            {

                                reliable = features[8].Substring(0, 3);
                            }
                            else
                                reliable = features[8].Substring(0, 1);


               xml = new XElement("DOC", 
                    new XAttribute("Relevance", c1.relevance),
                    new XElement("Date", get_time[1]),
                    new XElement("Author", get_name_comment[1]),
                    new XElement("Text", get_name_comment[3]),
                    new XElement("Favourite",features[9]),
                    new XElement("Peformance",perfor),
                    new XElement("Fuel",fuel),
                    new XElement("Fun",fun),
                    new XElement("Interior",interi),
                    new XElement("Exterior",exteri),
                    new XElement("Reliability",reliable)
                );
                       // xml = new XElement(get_car_name

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex) 
                        {
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: You want to store this xml in a file?

Comment: What is your question? What is not working?

Comment: I added more code  I wish to concat the xml in each iteration and after the loop i will save it to file

Comment: @Robust what is confusing me is that your two samples seem unrelated. What is the actual problem here? As long as the size isn't immense you can just append to the DOM. If the size is *huuuuge*, the XmlWriter is an option. Which applies in your scenario?

Comment: I did it this way every xelemnt I converted to string at the end of the loop and keep on concating that string , after loop I wrote in in an .xml file by string writer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it this way 
every xelemnt I converted to string at the end of the loop and keep on concating that string , after loop I wrote in in an .xml file by string writer

Answer (score 2):

```
xml.Save(path);
```

or was there something more subtle involved, that isn't in the question?

Comment: I added more code  I wish to concat the xml in each iteration and after the loop i will save it to file

Comment: @RobustRob you can't really concatenate xml documents, due to the need for a single outer root element. This leaves 2 options: rewrite *everything* each save, or: use something like `XmlWriter` to write in a forwards only stream

Comment: any hello world example will be very helpful particular to my case